# Jmeter Regular Expression Extractor find ItemID in xml

Tags: xml, regex, expression, jmeter, extractor

I am new to [jmeter](/questions/tagged/jmeter); I hope that I can describe my problem to you well enough.

I am trying to use regex to extract an ItemID attribute from an xml element. Which I then use in another request. This is the XML response I am trying to extract the ItemID from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Promise >
 <SuggestedOption>
      <Option TotalShipments="1">
           <PromiseLines TotalNumberOfRecords="1">
                <PromiseLine ItemID="Col_001" >
                     <Assignments>
                          <Assignment InteractionNo="1" >
                          </Assignment>
                     </Assignments>
                </PromiseLine>
           </PromiseLines>
     </Option>
 </SuggestedOption>
</Promise>
```

I have the Regular Expression Extractor set up as follows:

```
Reference Name: item
Regular Expression: .?ItemID=(.+?)*
Template: $1$
Match No.: 1
```

In the 2nd request I have set the ItemID as follows ... ItemID=${item} ...

I know that When I use the Default Value set to "Col_001" it works fine. So there is obviously a problem with my Expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
\bItemID\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ItemID                   'ItemID'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  =                        '='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use xpath extractor to do this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex:

```
ItemID="(.+)"
```